# Even after parsing the input values I'm getting NaN as an answer

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**//html code**


calculate

*Addition of two numbers*

```
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value); //input value1
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value); //input value2

var btn = document.getElementById("ans");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
      var result = x + y ;    //expression
      console.log(result);   // output as 'Nan'
      console.log(typeof(result)); // output as 'number'

});
```

Comment: i have entered integers as inputs. n1=10 & n2 =5 in the input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you have set default value to `x` & `y` as empty strings at start like:

```
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value); //input value1
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value); //input value2
```

So, no matter what values you enter in the inputs, you will always get `Nan`. Here's what is happening right now:

```js
var x = parseFloat(""); //input value1
var y = parseFloat(""); //input value2

var btn = document.getElementById("ans");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var result = x + y; //expression
  console.log(result); // output as 'Nan'
  console.log(typeof(result)); // output as 'number' 
});
```

```html
<button id="ans">ADD</button>
```

Only way to resolve this is to put the variables inside click, so that when the button is clicked then only you get the latest values of each input like:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("ans");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value); //input value1
  var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value); //input value2
  var result = x + y;
  console.log(result);
  console.log(typeof(result));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="text" id="n2">
<button id="ans">ADD</button>
```

Also, if you are only going to use numbers here, then you can use `<input type="number" />` instead of `<input type="text" />` like:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("ans");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value); //input value1
  var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value); //input value2
  var result = x + y;
  console.log(result);
  console.log(typeof(result));
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="n1">
<input type="number" id="n2">
<button id="ans">ADD</button>
```

Comment: if i declare the variable before the event occurs and parse the values inside event,then it should also work fine

Answer (score 1):

if we access the input field value before any event we get undefined so we can access the field value after generating the click event.

```js
<input type="text" id="n1" name="name">
    <input type="text" id="n2" name="emai">
    <input type="submit" id="ans" value="Submit">

    <script>


        var btn = document.getElementById("ans");
        btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
            var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value); 
            var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value); 
              var result = x + y ;    //expression
              console.log(result);   // output as 'Nan'
              console.log(typeof(result)); // output as 'number'

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("ans")
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
 let x = getFloat(getElVal("n1"))
 let y =  getFloat(getElVal("n2"))
 let result = x + y

 if (!isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y)) {
  console.log('valid op')
 }

 console.log(result);
 console.log(typeof(result))
 
 function getFloat(val) {
  return parseFloat(val)
 }

 function getElVal(id) {
  ele = document.getElementById(id)
  return ele? ele.value:undefined
 }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="text" id="n2">
<button id="ans">ADD</button>
```